# batch svn checkout windows server 2012

Tags: batch-file, tortoisesvn, windows-server-2012, runas

I wrote this `.bat` file:

```
runas /savecred /user:Domain\Username "svn checkout https://<Repository> <DestinationLocalFolder>"
```

To be able to automate the process of downloading source code, it has to be a `. bat` and it has to run as a different user than the one that is logged in. I tried it in my Windows 7 Workstation and it works perfect. But after trying it on the server, which also has TortoiseSVN, and all user settings that I checked are the same, it just opens an SVN window and immediately closes it.
I have also tried this with powershell:

```
powershell "runas /savecred /user:Domain\Username ""svn checkout https://<Repository> <DestinationLocalFolder>"""
```

Any ideas on why this does not work on the server would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I got it, all I needed to do was running an svn cleanup, because in my debugging I had interrupted a previous checkout process. After running an svn cleanup after interrupting the process, it works perfect.